# Ionic 4 ngIf binding

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

consulto cómo implementar *ngIf para este caso:

Tengo una variable string construida:
**varname = "a = 1 && b = 2 && c = 3 && d = 0";**

Quiero filtrar una lista con elementos (cards) que tienen las 4 propiedades, a, b, c y d. Propiedades que varían dinámicamente.

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo reemplazar la condición dentro de *ngIf ya que ***NO me acepta *ngIf = "{{varname}}"***

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me pudieran dar

```
Ionic:

  ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.11.0 (C:\Users\Estelita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
  Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
  @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
  @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
  @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
  @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins       : not available

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Android)
   NodeJS            : v12.13.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.12.1
   OS                : Windows 8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de usar la directiva `ngIf`. La más habitual (y en mi opinión la más práctica) es la siguiente:

```html
<div *ngIf="condicion; else bloqueElse">El contenido de este div se muestra cuando 'condicion' se cumple (true).</div>
<ng-template #bloqueElse>Este contenido se muestra cuando 'condicion' es false.</ng-template>
```

Tienes más información en la [documentación oficial](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) (en inglés).

De todos modos, si tienes cuatro casos diferentes, quizás te resulte más interesante `ngSwitch`. Se usa así:

```html
<container-element [ngSwitch]="propiedad">
   <div *ngSwitchCase="1">Esto se muestra si 'propiedad===1'</div>
   <div *ngSwitchCase="2">Esto se muestra si 'propiedad===2'</div>
   <div *ngSwitchCase="3">Esto se muestra si 'propiedad===3'</div>
   <div *ngSwitchDefault>Esto se muestra si 'propiedad' tiene otro valor</div>
</container-element>
```

Más documentación [aquí](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch).

Comment: Gracias nezah, pero son 4 propiedades diferentes, no 4 valores diferentes de la misma propiedad

Comment: Entiendo. Y la forma de usar el `ngIf` que detallo al comienzo de la respuesta tampoco te funciona?

Answer (score 0):

En el `ngIf` no puedes usar *string interpolation* pero puedes usar directamente las variables y funciones de tu archivo .ts en el cual está vinculado el html. Ejemplo

ts

```
varname = a === 1 && b === 2 && c === 3 && d === 0;
isTrue(): boolean {
   return varname;
}
```

html

```
<div *ngIf="varname">variable verdadera</div>
<div *ngIf="isTrue()">función retorna verdadero</div>
// También se puede usar las variables para una expresión booleana
<div *ngIf="a === 1 && b === 2 && c === 3 && d === 0">expresión verdadera</div>
```